# jest beforeEach is resolving promise before test

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

I want to test the state of my application before resolving a promise.
I'm creating the promise inside a beforeEach block, so I expect all my tests to execute before the promise is resolved.
But when the test gets executed, the promise was already resolved, and the code is in the post promise state.

```
// jest code
describe("sync beforeEach", () => {

    let promise;
    let state;

    beforeEach(() => {
        state = 'pending'
        promise = Promise.resolve().then(() => { state = 'resolved'; });
    });

    test('should run before resolve', async () => {
        // the promise is resolved and the bellow line fails.
        expect(state).toEqual('pending');
        await promise;
        expect(state).toEqual('resolved');
    });

});
```

I have implemented the exact same test using jasmine and it happens as I expected. The promise does not get resolved before the test, so the test pass.

```
// jasmine code
describe("sync beforeEach", () => {

    let promise;
    let state;

    beforeEach(() => {
        state = 'pending'
        promise = Promise.resolve().then(() => { state = 'resolved'; });
    });

    it('should run before resolve', async () => {
        // the promise is not resolved yet, so the bellow line pass
        expect(state).toEqual('pending');
        await promise;
        expect(state).toEqual('resolved');
    });

});
```

How to do the same test using jest?

Comment: you're asking for trouble; in the spec there's no need for `resolve().then(f)` to not be called synchronously; call the promise in the `it` or abstract it to a shared function if multiple tests need to run the code.

Comment: @TomMcKenzie. This was just an example. I'm not actually calling `then(f)`. But the entire `describe`  block is about testing the app state before the promise is resolving. Other promises might resolve before.
If I create a function to be called inside the `test` by all tests, why not just call it in the before each?
The jasmine way makes much more sense

Answer (score 4):

What about running the promise with await only when you need it to run. Example:

```js
describe("sync beforeEach", () => {
    let state;
    let promise;

    beforeEach(() => {
        state = 'pending'
        promise = ()=> new Promise((resolve) => {
            state = 'resolved';
            resolve(true);
        });
    });

    it('should run before resolve', async () => {
        // the promise is not resolved yet, so the bellow line pass
        expect(state).toEqual('pending');
        await promise();
        expect(state).toEqual('resolved');
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works for my simplified example. But it might not work for the actual code I have here.